# Mostrar el nombre de todos los usuarios de mi database

Tags: android, firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola, lo que necesito es mostrar el nombre de los usuarios que tengo en mi Database, pero no logro hacerlo, me podrían ayudar por favor.

cada un esta referenciado por la clave del usuario, muchas gracias.

```
 database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    addU = database.getReference(bdreference.userRefence);
    addU.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            key= dataSnapshot.getKey();
            nombre=dataSnapshot.child(key).child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
                Log.i("nombre",nombre);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ya que sin parte del codigo que estas desarrollando no podremos ayudarte bien. Gracias.

Comment: ¿y cual es el código que has intentado de esto?, te invito a realizar el [tour] y revisar como realizar una pregunta en el sitio mediante [ask].

Comment: Por que tenes esa ramificacion con dos IDS ? si debajo del getUid() ya podes poner el nombre, sino despues para obtenerlos tenes que agregar mas childs

Answer (score 1):

Lo suyo es que te [mires la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) sobre como recuperar datos. Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es recuperar la tabla users, y dentro de ella iterar sus filas e ir jugando con los campos que tiene:

```
mDatabase.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String nombre = map.get("nombre");

            // hacer algo con el NOMBRE

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
});
```

Comment: sin el map podes hacer un Log.e("Dato usuario",""+datasnapshot.getvalue();

Comment: ¿ Porque responder una respuesta que no se realizo con respecto al [help]? , además esto no resuelve la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Como dice el compañero arriba, para obtener el dato del usuario es facil, solo que te falta agregar el getUid para obtener el usuario, en donde dice child("users") es la ramificacion de donde viene, digamos que es la clave que engloba todos los Users ID , si no lo tienes le sacas la parte de child("users") y debes declarar un `mAuth` para identificar el usuario que quieres obtener el nombre. Ahora, si necesitas recuperar solo esos tres , te recomiendo concatenar los addValueEventListener con distintos dataSnapShot.

```
 mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


      String NombreUsuario=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.e("Nombre de usuario", "" + NombreUsuario);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: ¿ Porque responder una respuesta que no se realizo con respecto al [help]? , además esto no resuelve la pregunta.

Comment: si, es la forma de obtener el usuario, sabes alguna otra forma ?

Comment: gracias amigo, pero estoy buscando la forma de obtener todos los campos nombre, no solo el del usuario actual.

Comment: arriba te dije que tenes que concatenar las referencias